# inherit heroku addon configuration for review apps

Tags: heroku, heroku-api

My team has recently started using review apps. However, before tests can be run on a review app, we need to manually change the configuration of an addon. This manual step breaks our test workflow. Is there any way to transfer addon configuration to a review app?

Comment: If you have a specific example of something you're trying to configure, let me know and I'll update my answer. I believe you should be able to configure most things through "options", but it likely depends on the addon.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku allows you to specify addons for review apps in your `app.json` like so:

```
{
 …
 "addons": [
    {
      "plan": "heroku-postgresql",
      "as": "BACKUP_DATABASE",
      "options": {
         "version": "9.5"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that according [to the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#app-json), review apps are provisioned with the default "ephemeral" plan from the provider. Also, not all apps support review/CI apps.

If one of your addons does not support review apps, you should see an error message similar to `<add-on service slug> has opted out of supporting Review and CI apps` when the review app attempts to deploy.

Comment: yes i have been using the addon  part, with the options. However, for my specific addon (foundelasticsearch), i need to enable stored scripts, an option which is not available on the options.